how to install Qt platform plugin ( I am getting an error message when using matplotlib)?
How to install Qt platform plugin? I am getting an error message when using matplotlib.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.  
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.   
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

I'm not sure what command I should use.

Can you give us some context? What is your Ubuntu version and flavor? Are you using the system python3 or a third party installation such as conda/anaconda? How was matplotlib installed and what is the application?

I am indeed using anaconda/python 3 and matplotlib was (as far as I remember) installed with pip ; I have reelase python '3.8.19' and matplotlib '3.7.2'

From my experience with another plugin, after reinstalling the dependencies resolved my problem. You might consider reinstalling dependencies.
Also, if you suspect the issue is specific to xcb, you can try forcing another platform, such as offscreen or wayland.

Thanks for your reply

After reinstalling PyQt5 - pip install pyqt5 - I cannot import module QtCore : the error message is that the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.7 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.13. same problem with QtGui. This may be the reason why matplotlib.pyplot does not work?

Try to install:
sudo apt install libglu1-mesa-dev libx11-xcb-dev ‘^libxcb*’

Sometimes it is also necessary to install:
 sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0


1/Tried both commands but still no success when using matplotlib.pyplot.figure() - I have the same messsage error as before --> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
-->I then tried reinstalling PyQt5 again...(see next comment)

2/ pip install PyQt5 --> pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pyqtwebengine 5.15.6 requires PyQt5>=5.15.4, but you have pyqt5 5.12 which is incompatible.
pyqtwebengine 5.15.6 requires PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11, but you have pyqt5-sip 4.19.19 which is incompatible.
3/  new message error in matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
--> from .qt_compat import QT_API, _enum  --> RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.7 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.13
